# TextFormField i cant type anything

Tags: flutter

im facing a problem with TextFormField which when i type anything on the keyboard it doesn't appear in the text field, im trying doing a chat application with BLOC. Note : when i remove this line...emit(SocialGetMessageSuccessState()); i can type normaly and the problem is gone but 2 bugs appear..first one is that when i enter chat with someone the older messages don't appear unless i send him a new message...second one is when i enter a different chat with someone else the messages of the first user appears to the other user and to solve this one i should exit the chat page and enter again to see the messages of the wanted user that i currenlty chatting him/
the problem is when i type any character on the keyboard it won't print in the text field and it gives me this :
getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

here is my code

```
List<SocialUserModel> users =[];

  void getUsers()
  {
    if(users.length ==0)
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get().then((value)
    {
      value.docs.forEach((element)
      {
        if(element.data()['uId'] != userModel!.uId)
          users.add(SocialUserModel.fromJson(element.data()));
      });
      emit(SocialGetAllUsersSuccessState());
    })
        .catchError((error){
      emit(SocialGetAllUsersErrorState(error.toString()));
    });
  }

  void sendMessage({
  required String receiverId,
  required String dateTime,
  required String text,
})
{
  MessageModel model = MessageModel(
    text: text,
    senderId: userModel!.uId,
    receiverId: receiverId,
    dateTime: dateTime,
  );

  // set my chats

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userModel!.uId)
      .collection('chats')
      .doc(receiverId)
      .collection('messages')
      .add(model.toMap())
      .then((value){
        emit(SocialSendMessageSuccessState());
  })
      .catchError((error)
  {
        emit(SocialSendMessageErrorState());
  });

  // set receiver chats
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(receiverId)
      .collection('chats')
      .doc(userModel!.uId)
      .collection('messages')
      .add(model.toMap())
      .then((value){
    emit(SocialSendMessageSuccessState());
  })
      .catchError((error)
  {
    emit(SocialSendMessageErrorState());
  });
}

List<MessageModel> messages = [];

  void getMessages({
    required String receiverId,
  })
    {
     FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userModel!.uId!)
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(receiverId)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('dateTime')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event)
    {
      messages=[];
      event.docs.forEach((element)
      {
         messages.add(MessageModel.fromJson(element.data()));
      });
      emit(SocialGetMessageSuccessState());
    });
   }
```

//getUser screen

```
class ChatsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<SocialCubit,SocialStates>(
      listener: (context,state){},
      builder: (context,state)
      {
        return ConditionalBuilder(
          condition: SocialCubit.get(context).users.length > 0,
          builder: (context) => ListView.separated(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildChatItem(context,SocialCubit.get(context).users[index]),
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height:1),
              itemCount: SocialCubit.get(context).users.length
          ),
          fallback: (context) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        );
      }
    );
  }

  Widget buildChatItem(BuildContext context,SocialUserModel model) => InkWell(
    onTap: ()
    {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatDetailsScreen(userModel: model)));
    },
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Row(
        children:
        [
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 25,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              '${model.image}'
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 15,),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                '${model.name}',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

//ChatScreen

```
class ChatDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  SocialUserModel? userModel;
 final messageController = TextEditingController();
  ChatDetailsScreen({this.userModel}) {}
  @override

  Widget build (context) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context)
      {

        SocialCubit.get(context).getMessages(receiverId: userModel!.uId!);

        return BlocConsumer<SocialCubit,SocialStates>(
          listener: (context,state) {},
          builder: (context,state)
          {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                titleSpacing: 0,
                title: Row(
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 20,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userModel!.image!),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 15,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      userModel!.name!,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.separated(
                          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (context,index)
                          {
                            var message = SocialCubit.get(context).messages[index];
                            if(SocialCubit.get(context).userModel!.uId == message.senderId)
                              return buildMyMessage(message);
                            return buildMessage(message);
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (context,index) => SizedBox(height: 7,),
                          itemCount: SocialCubit.get(context).messages.length
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.grey[300]!,
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                      ),
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                      child: Row(
                        children:
                        [
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: messageController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: 'type your message here...',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: MaterialButton(onPressed:()
                            {
                              SocialCubit.get(context).sendMessage(
                                receiverId: userModel!.uId!,
                                dateTime: DateTime.now().toString(),
                                text: messageController.text,
                              );
                            },
                              minWidth: 1,
                              child: Icon(
                                IconBroken.Send,
                                size: 16,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

  Widget buildMessage(MessageModel model) => Align(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
    child: Container(
      decoration:BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[300],
          borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.only(
            bottomEnd: Radius.circular(10),
            topEnd: Radius.circular(10),
            topStart: Radius.circular(10),
          )
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 5,
        horizontal: 10,
      ),
      child: Text(
        model.text!,
      ),
    ),
  );
  Widget buildMyMessage(MessageModel model) => Align(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
    child: Container(
      decoration:BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.only(
            bottomStart: Radius.circular(10),
            topEnd: Radius.circular(10),
            topStart: Radius.circular(10),
          )
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 5,
        horizontal: 10,
      ),
      child: Text(
        model.text!,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

sory if i can't explain..still newbie here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem
i converted the stateless widget into stateful